# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

Bit of a weird one!

Could anyone shed some light on this `TypeError` message?

```
csvRow.append(len(calls["outbound"] + len(calls["inbound"])))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'
```

When I do the following, I get no issues and it runs as expected:

```
totalinbound = len(calls["inbound"])
totaloutbound = len(calls["outbound"])
csvRow.append(totalinbound + totaloutbound)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parenthesis are not balanced correctly.  `calls["outbound"]` should be inside the parenthesis that call the `len` function:

```
csvRow.append(len(calls["outbound"]) + len(calls["inbound"]))
#                                  ^
```

I moved a closing parethesis from the end of the line to where the arrow is.

Otherwise, you will be trying to add `len(calls["inbound"])` with the dict returned by `calls["outbound"]`.  This is a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.

```
# calculates the len of (dict + len of dict)
len(calls["outbound"] + len(calls["inbound"]))

# calculates the len of dict + len of dict
len(calls["outbound"]) + len(calls["inbound"])
```